# Variable inside an object context

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, object

How do I make `nav_items` work in the following context?

```
params = {
    nav: $('.nav'),
    nav_items: params.nav.find('li')
}

ReferenceError: params is not defined (logically true)
```

Also tried this:

```
params = {
    nav: $('.nav'),
    nav_items: nav.find('li')
}

ReferenceError: nav is not defined (what is the right way?)
```

I know, it can be done using this code:

```
params = {
    nav: $('.nav'),
    nav_items: null
}
params.nav_items = nav.find('li');
```

But its interesting, can it be done without an extra code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $nav = $('.nav');
params = {
    nav: $nav,
    nav_items: $nav.find('li')
}
```

Comment: you could wrap values in functions

Comment: @Steve: I don't see that adding an extra line is something to be worried about. I will use this as it is :)

Comment: $nav becomes a global, I'm trying to make it quite local.

Comment: @Steve `var` makes it local.

Comment: I would like to use it for more than 1 element, more than 10 extra elements can make code a bit messy.

Comment: var $nav seems to be a global for all common functions below

Comment: @Steve In that case, let me introduce you to my good friend, the `function` :  `function buildNav(selector){ var $n = $(selector); return { nav: $n, nav_items: $n.find('li') }; }` then `var params = buildNav('.nav');`

Comment: @asawyer thanks :) in that case I've to make some extra functions instead of variables. Quite odd way.

Comment: @Steve javascript lets you do some very weird things, so maybe? Reading the value of a partially constructed object, even if it is possible, seems like a really bad idea to me though.

Answer (score 2):

May be too late but could not refrain:

```
params = (function(a) { 
  return {nav: a, nav_items: a.find('li')};
})($('.nav'));
```

Comment: @Steve: Saw it after you accepted the answer. Could not avoid answering as your excepted answer does not meet your own required criteria.

Comment: Inlining the functions would be a bad call according to `I would like to use it for more than 1 element, more than 10 extra elements can make code a bit messy.`

Comment: @asawyer: Can't agree with you more! But Steve's requirement was such.